# Как сделать так, чтобы переменные из разных функций видели друг друга

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
try:
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import messagebox
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 import requests
 import lxml
 import re
 w = Tk()
 w.geometry('550x500')
 w.title('FindBy')
 numcountry = Label(w,text='+7')
 numcountry.place(x=0,y=0)
 e = Entry(w,width=20)
 e.place(x=20,y=0)
 def back_phone():
  global l,e
  vvod = e.get()
  req = requests.get('https://google'+vvod)
  b = bs(req.text,'lxml')
  result = b.find(class_='number-item').text
  need = result[170:270]
  need1 = re.sub('                          ','',need)
  l = Label(w, text=need1, font=('Corbel', 10, 'bold', 'roman'))
  l.place_forget()
  l.place(x=5,y=40)
  e.delete(0,END)
 def front_phone():
    l.place_forget()
    numcountry = Label(w, text='+7')
    numcountry.place(x=0, y=0)
    e = Entry(w, width=20)
    e.place(x=20, y=0)
    b = Button(w, text='Проверить', command=back_phone, fg='red', bg='black', activeforeground='white',activebackground='blue', bd=4)
    b.place(x=145, y=0)
    e.delete(0,END)
 def back_ip():
    l.place_forget()
    vvod1 = e.get()
    clearvvod = re.sub(' ','',vvod1)
    req1 = requests.get('https://yandex'+clearvvod)
    b1 = bs(req1.text, 'lxml')
    find1 = b1.find(class_='is-collapsed').text
    clear1 = find1[34:]
    clear2 = re.sub('\n\n','\n',clear1)
    iplabel = Label(w,text=clear2,width=20)
    iplabel.place_forget()
    iplabel.place(x=5,y=40)
    e.delete(0,END)
 def front_ip():
    global l,e
    l.place_forget()
    ipvvod = Label(w, text='IP:')
    ipvvod.place(x=0, y=0)
    e = Entry(w, width=20)
    e.place(x=20, y=0)
    b = Button(w, text='Проверить', command=back_ip, fg='red', bg='black', activeforeground='white',activebackground='blue', bd=4)
    b.place(x=145, y=0)
 def ex():
    exit()
 m = Menu()
 m1 = Menu(m)
 m2 = Menu(m1)
 m2.add_command(label='По номеру',command=front_phone)
 m2.add_command(label='По IP',command=front_ip)
 m1.add_cascade(label='Выбрать инструмент',menu=m2)
 m1.add_separator()
 m1.add_command(label='Выход',command=ex)
 m.add_cascade(label='Меню',menu=m1)
 w.config(menu=m)
 b = Button(w,text='Проверить',command=back_phone,fg='red',bg='black',activeforeground='white', activebackground='blue',bd=4)
 b.place(x=145,y=0)
 w.mainloop()
except ConnectionError:
    messagebox.showerror('Нет подключения','Проверьте подключение к интернету')
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы переменные из разных функций видели друг друга. Например, чтобы переменная front_phone видела переменную l из back_phone. Я пробовал global, return и не помогло.

Comment: вы же используете переменные w, e, numcountry, объявите там и l

Comment: Не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз в разных вариациях.